# how to create a 3d web service from a webscene(.3ws)

Tags: arcgis-server, web-scene

To get 3d visulisation of raster data, I have created a web scene(.3ws) from .sxd file of that raster data. Now i want the web service from this .3ws file.
  Please hel me how to get the url of that webservice.

Answer (score 1):

Login or create an ArcGIS online account. In the "My Content" section, click add item, and upload the .3ws file. It will give you a URL on the next page.